# userform vba opening animation

Tags: vba, animation, userform

I have a question regarding the loading and unloading animation of userforms in vba. So usually when you open or close a userform the window does not just pop up instantly but there is a small animation (just as you would normally open windows in Windows so it does just pop up from one frame to another but has a certain time where it "fades" into/out of the screen, if it not clear what I mean with that I am happy to answer and explain again)

Anyway so normally when I call

```
UserformTest.Show vbModal
```

or

```
Unload UserformTest
```

this userform is shown/ unloads with that certain animation. My program consists of multiple userforms each loading each other ( just like a normal program where you have buttons with "next" where the current uform unloads and a new one is being shown...

But I face this problem that (only sometimes) at some point there is no animation when I load/unload new userforms instead they appear or vanish instantly (when I want them to). So there is just no animation anymore.

And I do not know for sure why that is and where it comes from. I have the suspect that it comes from the modal ( so vbModal or vbModeless) with which I call them.

It is just a bit weird since sometimes it works perfectly but sometimes there is point where there are no animations anymore (if I then close the Userform completely and open it again the problem remains, only a restart of my computer can then change it)

Did somebody face a similar problem? Could the reason maybe be my computer/CPU that if it has to do a lot of work it just drops the animation.

Very happy for any thoughts

Thank you so much in advance
Jonas